# Disable clicks when the tab has been clicked in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I am having this problem.
In my code when I repeatedly click on the tab: mod-2 or mod-3, the border will continue to expand. How to stop when the tab is clicked?

Problem 2: How do I check if code div class="l-item" already exists in html? If it already exists, will the .wrapInner in js stop running?:

```
$('.vd-list li').wrapInner('<div class="l-item"></div>');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/b9tcvjxg/

```js
$('.mod-1').on('click', function() {
  $('.display-tab .on').removeClass('on');
  $(this).addClass('on');
  $('.vd-list').removeClass('mod-2').removeClass('mod-3').addClass('mod-1');
  $('.vd-list .l-item').contents().unwrap();
  $('.vd-list .v-date, .vd-list .v-info-i:last-child, .vd-list .v-desc').show();
});

$('.mod-2').on('click', function() {
  $('.display-tab .on').removeClass('on');
  $(this).addClass('on');
  $('.vd-list').removeClass('mod-1').removeClass('mod-3').addClass('mod-2');
  $('.vd-list li').wrapInner('<div class="l-item"></div>');
  $('.vd-list .v-date, .vd-list .v-info-i:last-child').hide();
  $('.vd-list .v-desc').show();
  return false;
});

$('.mod-3').on('click', function() {
  $('.display-tab .on').removeClass('on');
  $(this).addClass('on');
  $('.vd-list').removeClass('mod-1').removeClass('mod-2').addClass('mod-3');
  $('.vd-list li').wrapInner('<div class="l-item"></div>');
  $('.vd-list .v-date, .vd-list .v-info-i:last-child, .vd-list .v-desc').hide();
});
```

```css
.tab-list {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.tab-list li {
  float: left;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #222;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mod-2 .l-item,
.mod-3 .l-item {
  border: 3px solid #111;
}

.mod-1 .r::after {
  content: "Mod 1";
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mod-2 .r::after {
  content: "Mod 2";
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mod-3 .r::after {
  content: "Mod 3";
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="tab-list display-tab">
  <li class="mod-1 on">Mod 1</li>
  <li class="mod-2">Mod 2</li>
  <li class="mod-3">Mod 3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="vd-list mod-1">
  <li>
    <div class="l"></div>
    <div class="r">
      <div class="v-desc">desc</div>
      <div class="v-info">
        <span class="v-info-i">1</span>
        <span class="v-info-i">2</span>
        <span class="v-info-i">3</span>
      </div>
      <div class="v-date">date</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The borders appear to get bigger on successive clicks because you append a new `.l-item` element each time: `wrapInner('<div class="l-item"></div>')`. It's not clear what your goal is in order to debug this for you effectively, though

Comment: DRY: Don't repeat yourself. removeClass on siblings and addClass on clicked element

Comment: I want to click on mod-2 and mod-3 continuously, the border will not expand. wrapInner ('<div class = "l-item"> </div>') will only be added when first clicked. The following clicks will not be added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
$('.mod-2').on('click', function() {
  $('.display-tab .on').removeClass('on');
  $(this).addClass('on');

  $('.vd-list').removeClass('mod-1').removeClass('mod-3').addClass('mod-2');

  var alrdyExists = $(".vd-list").find(".l-item").length > 0;
    if(!alrdyExists) {
       $('.vd-list li').wrapInner('<div class="l-item"></div>');
    }

  $('.vd-list .v-date, .vd-list .v-info-i:last-child').hide();
  $('.vd-list .v-desc').show();
    return false;
});
```

This will only border mod-2 content once as it checks whether mod-2 already contains l-item by using `find` and checking the length of the result.

You can apply the same method to the mod-3 on click.

Here is a working fiddle just in case: http://jsfiddle.net/e3fjqnhb/2/

Comment: My question seems confusing. But your simple answer solved my problem. Thanks for the help